# Bitbake Building errors

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I used the command

```
$ bitbake angstrom-lxde-image 2>&1 | tee -a  buildoutput.txt
```

but got the following error.

> ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL:
>   'https://www.khronos.org/registry/khronos_headers.tgz;name=gles-h'.
>   Unable to fetch URL from any source.
>
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
>   /home/vqhost/oe-core/build/out-eglibc/work/colibri_t20-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/trdx-nv-binaries-1.0-r11/temp/log.do_fetch.6970
>   NOTE: recipe trdx-nv-binaries-1.0-r11: task do_fetch: Failed
>
> ERROR: Task 1659
>   (/home/vqhost/oe-core/build/../stuff/meta-toradex/recipes/trdx-nv-binaries/trdx-nv-binaries.bb,
>   do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

So please guide me on how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the download from the URL fails. Going to the URL with curl or your browser will show you the following error: *The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.*. Looking at the URL indicates that the file is extended with *;name=gles-h* for unknown reasons.

So find the code in meta-toradex, actually the error tells you exactly in which file: *meta-toradex/recipes/trdx-nv-binaries/trdx-nv-binaries.bb*

In the meta-toradex repository we won't find this URL in the current git HEAD,. But we find the following:

```
# the khronos headers are taken from here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/khronos_headers.tgz
# this tarball changes from time to time breaking the receipe, thus it is provided with the recipe
SRC_COMMON =  " \
    [...]
    file://khronos_headers.tgz \
    [...]
```

Since this is git HEAD, I would check this against your current code and adjust it by either

- updating to the latest version that works for your environment or
- creating a new package that fixes the broken one (creating .bbappend file in its own layer if you are not familiar how to do this in Yocto)

Oh, I always like it when I find stackoverflow questions that are asked exactly the same somewhere else: https://communities.intel.com/message/309955

Comment: The `;name=gles-h` is not actually used when fetching the uri: it's just metadata for bitbake. The actual URL was 404 for a time (proving the comment in the recipe) but works now.

Comment: @jku: Yes, thats the theory. But the error gave me more the impression that it is not cut of as expected.  Naming the file gles-h doesn't make any sense (especially if it is a tgz file) to me, too. And the download works as soon as you remove it. Maybe a older yocto version...